# I want to read PDF file in python want the the particular output of that pdf file iin excel with the help of python?

Tags: python

So i want to pull sepcific value from a pdf invoice and put that value in excel, we can do this when there is only 2 to 3 files but if there is hundred of files.

## Will it be possible that we can automate this task with the help of python

If i get a code in python for how to automate this process.

Comment: use PyPDF2 package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.